# Regex simply not working in IE 8, 9 and 10

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, replace

Here is our text to replace:

```
<A href="http://domain.com"><IMG src="https://domain.com/images/siteheader.jpg"></A>
```

Using javascript .replace, we try to replace with blank space using the following:

```
.replace ("/<A href=\"http:\/\/domain.com\"><IMG src=\"https:\/\/domain.com\/images\/siteheader.jpg\"><\/A>/i"," ");
```

In all other browsers this seems to work, but not in IE. I even tried using this online regex validator: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/regexp-editor.php and it says it's valid. Kind of stumped. Is IE doing something out of the norm?

Comment: IE does things out of the norm by default on purpose, that should not come as a surprise!

Answer (score 6):

You *either* use a string (the literal form of which looks like `"..."`) *or* a regular expression (the literal form of which looks like `/.../`) with `replace`. You're trying to do both simultaneously. Remove the quotes:

```
.replace (/<A href="http:\/\/domain.com"><IMG src="https:\/\/domain.com\/images\/siteheader.jpg"><\/A>/i, " ");
```

When you use a string, it's just matched literally, no regular expression processing is done.

I haven't validated the entire contents of the regex, just removed the surrounding `"` and removed the `\` in front of the embedded `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are literals and should not have quotes around them:

```
.replace(/your regex here/,'replacement')
```

That being said, where is the text coming from? If it's coming from `.innerHTML`, browsers may return a string that is different from what you literally have in the source (for instance, attribute names may be uppercased, or the attributes themselves swapped. I believe older versions of IE strip out quotes around single-word attribute values, which would also mess with your regex.

In short, you should not use a regex for this. You could try this instead:

```
var toRemove = document.querySelector("a[href='http://domain.com']"),
    parent = toRemove.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(toRemove);
```